# What is JSON code to display boolean value as "yes" or "no"?

Tags: json

This code works but rather than display the words "true" or "false" I want it return "yes" or "no" based on what is in @currentField.

```
{
 "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "div",
"txtContent": "@currentField",
"style": {
    "color": {
        "operator": "?",
        "operands": [
            {
            "operator": "<=",
            "operands": [
                "[$Handouts_x0020_Complete]",
                0
            ]
            },
            "red",
            ""
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing

```
"txtContent": "@currentField",
```

to use an excel style expression like

```
"txtContent": "=if(@currentField == 1, 'yes', 'no') ",
```